# Not able to record the browser action in jmeter 5.3

Tags: jmeter

I am using J-meter version 5.3, I have done all the setup like configuring the certificate for the Firefox browser and the network set up which is required J-meter to capture the browser action.

Still, I am not able to view the action steps on the left-hand side of the J-meter.

Though it is my learning stage of the J-meter and I have done all the research to solve my problem but not able to get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

F-irefox browser is bypassing p-roxy for any [l-ocalhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) a-ddresses since [F-irefox 6-7](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1535581) therefore J-meter proxy is ignored by the F-irefox.

1. Type `about:config` in the address bar of your F-irefox
2. Look for `network.proxy.allow_hijacking_localhost` setting
3. Change it to `true`

This way you will be able to send your F-irefox traffic through J-Meter proxy and will see the recorded requests.

If you're recording [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) traffic you will also need to install J-Meter's self-signed certificate into F-irefox, follow instructions from the **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of [J-Meter Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) for instructions.

Just in case be aware of an alternative way of recording a J-Meter script - [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and SSL certificates.